# In Angular 9, how do I update a component's data field to show in the DOM without re-instantiating it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular 9. I have a program where a user enters in a name - which, upon submitting - a POST HTTP request is sent and the name is stored. I then have an unrelated component for a sub-header that lists the names that have been stored using a GET HTTP request using ngOnInit(). However, I need the sub-header to update that list of names dynamically each time a new list is entered rather than just whenever the component instantiates.

I'm unsure how to proceed. I'm sure I could simply add a button that fetches and updates said list, but trying for something more dynamic. Thanks in advance!

````
//SERVICE.TS...

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { NewList } from './new-list.model';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListService {

  createdLists: NewList[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createList(postData) {
    return this.http
      .post(
        'API_KEY',
        postData
      );
  }

  getLists() {
    return this.http
      .get<NewList>(
        'API_KEY'
      ).pipe(map(responseData => {
            const responseArray: NewList[] = [];
            for (const key in responseData) {
              responseArray.push(responseData[key])
            }
            return responseArray;
          })
        );
  }
}




// NEW-LIST-MENU.TS (USER ENTERS A NAME)...

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ListService } from 'src/app/shared/list.service';
import { NewList } from 'src/app/shared/new-list.model';
import { UIService } from 'src/app/shared/ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-list-menu',
  templateUrl: './new-list-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-list-menu.component.css']
})
export class NewListMenuComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private listService: ListService,
              private uiService: UIService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    const listName = form.value.listname;
    const newListObj = new NewList(listName, []);
    
    this.listService.createList(newListObj)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      });

    const lists = this.listService.updateLists(newListObj);
    
    
    form.reset();
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

}





// SUB-HEADER.TS...

import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ListService } from 'src/app/shared/list.service';
import { NewList } from 'src/app/shared/new-list.model';

import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPlusCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faList } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faSignOutAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-header.component.css']
})
export class SubHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  createdLists: NewList[];

  faWindowClose = faWindowClose;
  faPlusCircle = faPlusCircle;
  faList = faList;
  faSignOutAlt = faSignOutAlt;

  @Output() closeSub = new Subject();

  constructor(private listService: ListService, 
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listService.getLists().subscribe((responseData) => {
      this.createdLists = responseData;
    });
  }

  onCloseSelect() {
    this.closeSub.next();
  }

  onNewListSelect() {
    this.onCloseSelect();
    this.router.navigate(['new-list-menu']);
  }

  onLogOutSelect() {

  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in many ways, as these components are not related to each other, you can introduce a state service and use observables. see below possible solution

1. Create a new state service ListStateService

   ```
    export class ListStateService {
        private listData = new BehaviorSubject<NewList >({} as NewList);       
        listData$ = this.listData .asObservable();
    }
   ```
2. Inject ListStateService into NewListMenuComponent

In the onSubmit, after you update,

```
 const lists = this.listService.updateLists(newListObj);
    this.listData .next(lists );
```

3. Inject ListStateService into SubHeaderComponent
   In the ngOnInit(), subscribe to the ListStateService.listData$ and here you will get the value on changes

Answer (score 0):

In your service, use an event emitter (very useful):

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Output() myEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

then emit new data to your sub header component through your service like so:

```
emitEvent (newData: Array<string>) {
    this.myEvent.emit({
        data: newData,
    });
}
```

Subscribe to new data in your sub header component `ngOnInit` and use it:

```
this.myService.myEvent.subscribe((newData: Array<string>) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newData.data));
});
```

Note: Subscriptions will cause memory leaks if constantly re-subscribed in the component, so you can save the subscription and call `unsubscribe()` on it in the `ngOnDestroy` callback.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to pass data from a parent component to a child component, you can do this either with Input fields or a ViewChild

to use Input fields your parent might looks like this:

```
<app-sub-header [names]="names"></app-sub-header>
```

then use an "Input" field in the child. Updating names in the parent should update the same named variable in the child in real time.